# Program in C is showing a wrong result, Odd Number

Tags: c

Enter number of integers to be stored : 5

Enter 5 integers:

```
 1 2 3 4 5
```

There are 2 even numbers in the set.
There are 3 odd numbers in the set.

Even numbers:

```
2
4
```

Odd numbers:

```
1
3
5
```

Output:

```
Sum of Odd Numbers is 51
Sum of Even Numbers is 6
--------------------------------
Process exited after 3.389 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int N, n;
    printf("Enter number of integers to be stored : ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int count[N];
    printf("\nEnter %d integers: \n", N);
    for(int n=0;n<N;n++)    
    {
      scanf("%d", &count[n]);
    }
    //Even and Odd Counter
    int even_counter=0, odd_counter=0;
    for(n=0;n<N;n++)
    {
        //even_counter
        if(count[n]%2==0)
        {
            even_counter++;
        }
        //odd_counter
        else
        {
            odd_counter++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nThere are %d even numbers in the set.", even_counter);
    printf("\nThere are %d odd numbers in the set.\n", odd_counter);


    //Sorting of Even and Odd
    int i=0;
    printf("\nEven numbers: \n");
    for(n=0;n<N;n++)
    {   
        if(count[n]%2==0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", count[n]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nOdd numbers: \n");
    for(n=0;n<N;n++)
    {
        if(count[n]%2==1)
        {
            printf("%d\n", count[n]);
        }
    }

    //Sum of Odd and Even Values

    //EvenSummation
    int even_lister[i], sumEven, odd_lister[i], sumOdd;
    for(n=0;n<N;n++)
    {   
        if(count[n]%2==0)
        {
            even_lister[i]=count[n];
            sumEven+=even_lister[i];
        }
        else //OddSummation      
        {
            int odd_lister[i], sumOdd, i=0;

            odd_lister[i]=count[n];
            sumOdd+=odd_lister[i];

        }
     }
     printf("\nSum of Odd Numbers is %d", sumOdd);
     printf("\nSum of Even Numbers is %d", sumEven);
}
```

What's wrong with my program? I've tried everything I knew :(
The odd value is giving strange results.

Comment: This hardly looks like valid C, or C++ for that matter. Why is your declaration for `odd_lister` right after `else` and opening `{`?

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. Particularly about uninitialized variables.

Comment: Can you help me out? i'm beginning to learn C. Why is it that it is showing a wrong result?

Comment: Even though I make it as a global variable, it still return the same result.

Comment: You forgot to initialize `sumEven` and `sumOdd` to `0`, so their initial values could be anything.  Add `=0` to their declarations.  Always remember to initialize counters.

Comment: thanks Tom, I got it :)

Comment: Oops, still got it wrong. tried to initialize sumeven and sumodd to zero but it gives me a result for Odd number : 15

Comment: Your use of `i` seems to be wrong.  `i` is always `0`.  So you're declaring two zero-length arrays, then trying to store to them.  That won't work.  (1) Their lengths need to be `even_counter` and `odd_counter`.  (2) When storing to them, you need to increment the index each time to move to the next element.

Comment: @TomKarzes Don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the part where you calculate the sum of even numbers, which works:

```
    if(count[n]%2==0)
    {
        even_lister[i]=count[n];
        sumEven+=even_lister[i];
    }
```

Now here's the part where you calculate the sum of odd numbers, which doesn't:

```
    else //OddSummation      
    {
        int odd_lister[i], sumOdd, i=0;

        odd_lister[i]=count[n];
        sumOdd+=odd_lister[i];

    }
```

Do you see the difference? There's an extra line in the second one. In the version that doesn't work, you re-declared some local variables and assigned your values to those local variables. That's *why* it doesn't work. You didn't do anything with the "original" variables in a higher-up scope that you later print to the screen.

Furthermore, both parts are actually broken because you never initialised either `sumEven` or `sumOdd` to `0`, so their values are unspecified, and you're adding to unspecified values to create other unspecified values. Whether this bug creates an observable symptom or not is undefined.

Another problem is that you declare your arrays like this:

```
int even_lister[i];
```

but `i` is a variable that you set to `0` and never changed. So those arrays have *zero length* and every single access to them is illegal. Perhaps you meant to use `n` instead?

You really need to turn on your compiler warnings and read your code more carefully.

Comment: That solved it. Thanks to you guys. I'll remember that redeclaration will redeclare the variables that can give me wrong results. and I should initialize a variable when necessary to zero. thanks!

Comment: @AsherManangan Good luck and have fun